# pandas df explode and implode to remove specific dict from the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with multiple columns. On the the column called `request_headers` is in a format of list of dictionaries, example:

```
[{"name": "name1", "value": "value1"}, {"name": "name2", "value": "value2"}]
```

I would like to remove only those elements from that list which do contains specific name. For example with:

```
blacklist = "name2"
```

I should get the same dataframe, with all the columns including `request_headers`, but it's value (based on the example above) should be:

```
[{"name": "name1", "value": "value1"}]
```

How to achieve it ? I've tried first to explode, then filter, but was not able to "implode" correctly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use a .apply function:

```
blacklist = 'name2'
df['request_headers'] = df['request_headers'].apply(lambda x: [d for d in x if blacklist not in d.values()])
```

Comment: It's slower than the list comprehension and potentially incorrect, this will filter a dictionary even if blacklist is in another value than the name (or maybe I misunderstood the question?)

Answer (score 2):

Exploding is expensive, rather us a list comprehension:

```
blacklist = "name2"

df['request_headers'] = [[d for d in l if 'name' in d and d['name'] != blacklist]
                         for l in df['request_headers']]
```

Output:

```
                          request_headers
0  [{'name': 'name1', 'value': 'value1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([{"name": "name1", "value": "value1"}, {"name": "name2", "value": "value2"}])
blacklist = "name2"
col1=df1.name.eq(blacklist)
df1.loc[col1]
```

out：

```
    name   value
1  name2  value2
```